# Hibernate - Transactional does not save changes

Tags: java, hibernate

I use following methods to save changes to the database:

BaseService.java

```
    @Transactional
    public void update(TEntity entity) {
        entityManager.merge(entity);
        afterUpdate(entity);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void afterUpdate(TEntity entity) {
        // can be implemented in derived class to handle 'after' update operations
    }
```

In one of the derived classes I override `afterUpdate` method in a following way:

```
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void afterUpdate(Entity entity) {
        entity.setProperties(...);
        entityManager.merge(entity);
    }
```

But the `merge` does not save any changes - it does not trigger any SQL statement to database. As far as I know is that `merge` does not trigger SQL statement immediately but after the method annotated with `Transactional` ends it should save it to the database.

But it does not happen in this case.

If I put `entityManager.flush();` after `entityManager.merge(entity);` in `afterUpdate` it works fine.

But my goal is to avoid `flush` as I think it is not necessary here (`Transactional` should take care of it).

What am I doing wrong so it is not saved without explicit calling of `flush`?

Comment: Are these methods getting called from within the same class?

Comment: no, `update` is called on base class and `afterUpdate` is called on derived class.